# How to distribute app through Testflight for Beta testing iPhone apps on iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Since Apple requires you to use Testflight through iTunes Connect now to beta test apps, and Testflight requires iOS 8 in order to download...how can I test my app on previous iOS versions (without having physical access to the phone)?

Comment: You would have to use provisioning profiles and old UDID methods to test on 100 or less devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ad-hoc to test on 100 or less devices which has been registed.